# How can I sum the middle elements of an expanding list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, sum, expand

So far I know how to expand a list from its ends, but they end up getting doubled because of the first condition, which is to double a singleton. Would it make sense for the code to be like this:

```
sumExpand :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

sumExpand l = expand l []
  where
    expand [] a     = a
    expand (x:[]) a = x: expand [] (x:a)
    expand (x:xs) a = expand (x:a) (expand xs a)
```

And for me to work on its output:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3] from [1,2,3]
instead of [1,3,5,3]
```

The latter being my desire? Here's how I got to a temporary solution for a list of two elements:

```
expand (x:xs) a = x: tail (expand (map (x+) xs) (last xs:a))
```

---

Output:

```
*Main> sumExpand [1,2]
[1,3,2]
*Main> sumExpand [1,2,3]
[1,7,4,3]
```

---

EDIT: basically, I want the algorithm to work like this: `[a, b, c] => [a, a+b, b+c, c]`

Comment: What precisely is your algorithm supposed to do? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: You want to insert the sum of each adjacent pair between the pair? `[a, b, c] => [a, a+b, b, b + c, c]`?

Comment: What I want to do is the following: `[a, b, c] => [a, a+b, b+c, c]`. It's basically the same as what @chepner suggested, but without b repeating itself.

Comment: How about more than 3 elements in list? say, [a, b, c, d] => [a, a+b, b+c, c+d, d]?

Comment: I have the solution, but could you give me any pointers on how to improve my research or problem solving skills, for when stuff like this happens? I just got down voted and I want to improve. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, all you want to compute component-wise sums between your input list and  a shifted version of it:

```
a   b   c   d   e
    a   b   c   d   e
---------------------------
a  a+b b+c c+d d+e  e
```

Fill each empty slot with a 0 (`0:x` and `x++[0]`), and you just need `zipWith`

```
> (\x -> zipWith (+) (0:x) (x++[0])) [1,2,3]
[1,3,5,3]
```

Comment: If performance is a concern, this should be written `\x -> zipWith (+) (x++[0]) (0:x)`. It's not a big deal, but it's nice to let `zipWith` fuse with `(++)`.