# Haskell: how do you slide and sum a list to the right more than once?

Tags: list, haskell, sum, slide

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398705/2535251) answer to a problem that I failed to explain, but was considered useful due to its outline and solution, the list was shifted to the right once, and addition was used between this list and the initial one, to produce outputs like these:

```
[1,2] -> [1,3,2]
[1,2,3] -> [1,3,5,3]
[1,2,3,4] -> [1,3,5,7,4]
```

It was an answer that I rewrote to suit my needs like this:

```
slideSum :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

slideSum l = slideRight l []
  where
    slideRight [] a = a
    slideRight (x:[]) a = (x:a)
    slideRight (x:y:zs) a = slideLeft (x:a) (slideRight (sum (x:y:a):a) (slideLeft (y:zs) a))
      where
        slideLeft [] a = a
        slideLeft (x:[]) a = (x:a)
        slideLeft (x:y:zs) a = slideRight (sum (x:y:a):a) (slideLeft (y:zs) a)
```

---

And what it does is to keep the first and last elements intact, sum the first two and the following pair, for which I had to go left and right. When I tried to rewrite this for the following outputs:

`[1,2,3] -> [1,3,6,5,3]` `[1,2,3,4] -> [1,3,6,10,9,7,4]`

That is to *shift the first list as many times as the number of elements minus one* to sum them, I could not arrive at a solution that I considered to be natural, because I had to manipulate the result of two smaller expressions by dropping one element. This is the problem illustrated:

```
  0:0:1:2:3:[]    
  0:1:2:3:0:[]    0:1:2:[]
  1:2:3:0:0:[]    1:2:0:[]
+ ------------  + --------
  1:3:6:5:3:[]    1:3:2:[]
```

And this is how I manipulated its result, which I want to avoid:

```
slideSum :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
slideFromLeft :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
slideFromRight :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

slideFromLeft l = slideRight l []
  where
    slideRight [] a = a
    slideRight (x:[]) a = (x:a)
    slideRight (x:y:zs) a = slideRight (x:a) (slideRight (sum (x:y:a):zs) a)

slideFromRight l = slideLeft l []
  where
    slideLeft [] a = a
    slideLeft (x:[]) a = (x:a)
    slideLeft (x:y:zs) a = slideLeft (sum (x:y:zs):a) (slideLeft (y:zs) a)

slideSum l = slideFromLeft l ++ (tail slideFromRight l)
```

---

Does the nature of this problem require a different thought process or is the solution in need of its problem to be split into smaller parts? Can you slide the initial list and produce different results by keeping the former in memory?

Comment: Why don't you use [chepners solution to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398705/745903), which is about 700% nicer than your manual-recursion one and also much easier to generalise to the problem you're now asking about?

Comment: @leftaroundabout That is the solution that I linked to and had already upvoted, which I agree is much better than mine (and I wish to mature to that point), although I wanted to provide context for the next problem. I think that I need to count the elements on the list in its initial state and save it in memory so that I can count down from there and work on the result without changing the first list. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is apparently

```
foo :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
foo xs = map sum . transpose . take n . map (take (n+n-1))
                 . map (++ repeat 0) . iterate (0:) $ xs
   where
   n = length xs
```

See? Since Haskell is lazy, we don't care if we add more 0s than are actually needed. It will all get sorted out in the end by lazy evaluation.

Testing:

```
> foo [1..2]
[1,3,2]

> foo [1..3]
[1,3,6,5,3]

> foo [1..4]
[1,3,6,10,9,7,4]
```

We can make it properly non-strict so it works with infinite lists as well by throwing away the `length` computation, using `zipWith const` instead,

```
bar :: (Integral b) => [b] -> [b]
bar xs  =  map sum . zipWith take [1..]
                . transpose 
                . zipWith (const id) xs  
                . map (zipWith (const id) (xs ++ drop 1 xs))
                . map (++ repeat 0) . iterate (0:) $ xs
```

though all these `take`s, explicit and otherwise, make it look a bit too busy.

Or we could use `diagonals` from one of the packages that define it.

Comment: I consider the problem solved and I will work to consider the solution useful to me, because I believe that this is idiomatic (remember that I'm new), but I will definitely cast the vote later when I can look at it and understand it fully. Thank you!

Comment: I prefer `flip const` to `const id` for clarity.

Comment: @dfeuer I like KI because combinators. but also clarity. it lets me work through it mentally one thing at a time whereas with `flip const` I must see it applied to two things at once. thus `zipWith (const id) xs` for example, is *clearly* the equivalent of `take (length xs)` full stop. with `flip const` I need to think about the second list for some reason when all I have in mind is the first list's length.